# Existing frameworks to implement a REST-ful API framework with authentication/authorization and exponential backoff

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, exponential-backoff

I wanted to know if there are existing frameworks to build a REST-ful API with authentication/authorization and extra features like exponential backoff. The framework that I am looking for similar features is not unlike Google's [Cloud API](https://cloud.google.com/apis/). I know that I can re-invent the wheel and implement a homegrown solution with frameworks like [Spring-Boot](http://spring.io/projects/spring-boot), but I'm wondering if there's already something available or open-source that I can use.

For features like exponential backoff, I can imagine getting into engineering and design problems on how to keep track of user requests and then denying them if the requests are too aggressive. For features like authentication/authorization, that could become pretty hairy (user management/registration, token generation, ...).

If there are any code samples or small projects on HOWTO architect and implement such a REST-ful service I would appreciate that too.

Comment: Have you considered to combine _Spring Boot_ with _Spring Web MVC_ and _Spring Security_?

Comment: I think Spring Boot + Security is enough. I won't be using a MVC application; it's all REST-ful. I just didn't want to do the plumbing with Spring.

Comment: What do you want to use instead of Spring Web MVC?